# Change the background color of immediate subview of UIViewController using UIAppearence

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, uiappearance

I want to change the background color of all the `UIViewController` views. I have several `UIViewController` classes in my project and i want to set the same  background of all views once using `UIAppearence`.

I tried the following code:

```
[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:
    [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundImage"]]];
```

but it change the background color of every UIView including (`UIButton`, `UIView` subclasses and `UILabels` etc.)

Is there any way to handle this situation, so that i can only change the background color of `UIViewController` views? I googles a lot but i didn't find any relevent solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: Are you looking to affect only the root view of a view controller (`self.view`)?  That isn't really a case this is set up for.  You could swizzle `-[UIViewController setView:]` or make your own base class.

Comment: I want to do this for all UIViewController classes.

Answer (score -1):

Well I think the best is to subclass UIViewController and in viewDidLoad set the backgroundColor. But if you want to use UIAppearance you can do something like this :

```
id proxy = [UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIViewController class],nil];
[proxy setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundImage"]]
```

Comment: your code is not working. I am getting error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'UIAppearance'".

Comment: At the start of my answer I said what I will do, that is subclass UIViewController or UIView to change the background color. I answered too fast at your question, basically what you are trying to do is not possible through UIAppearance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.